# ⚠️ Error while updating location The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 1.)

Tags: ios, swift, location

`⚠️ Error while updating location The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 1.)` Why am I getting this error? It was working for a long time and suddenly I began receiving this error. I read other's solutions of just restarting their devices and Xcode and updating and all that but nothing has worked so far.

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation
import UIKit

class LocationDelegate: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var headingCallback: ((CLLocationDirection) -> ())? = nil
    var locationCallback: ((CLLocation) -> ())? = nil
    var bearing = 0.0
    var speed = 0.0


    var speedCallBack: ((CLLocation) -> ())? = nil

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let currentLocation = locations.last else { return }
        locationCallback?(currentLocation)
        speedCallBack?(currentLocation)

        var location: CLLocation = locations.last!
        speed = location.speed
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
        headingCallback?(newHeading.trueHeading)
        bearing = newHeading.trueHeading
    }

    func returnMPHSpeed() -> Double {
        //print ("speed : ", speed)
        return speed * 2.23602484472
    }

    func returnKMHSpeed() -> Double {
        return speed
    }

    func returnHeading() -> Int {
        return Int(bearing)
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("⚠️ Error while updating location " + error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: That api has a limit of 50 hits per minute.

Comment: What does that tell me? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You are getting the location using Apple's API right? I got this error when i hit the api more than 50 times in a minute. Make sure you are not calling the API more than 50 times a minute. If you need more than 50 locations, get the locations in such a way that you don't go over 50 in a minute.

Comment: How do I check how often I hit the api and then change it?

Comment: You would know because you are the one explicitly calling it? You can't change the limit. You can call the API with a delay for each hit so that it doesn't hit more than 50 calls a minute.

Comment: All I'm doing is: `let locationManager: CLLocationManager = {
        $0.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        $0.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        $0.startUpdatingLocation()
        $0.startUpdatingHeading()
        return $0
    }(CLLocationManager())`

Comment: @RakeshaShastri you are thinking of the geo coding APIs. This is straight Core Location updates on the device. There is no rate limit; you can expect updates about 1 per second

Comment: @GeorgeEdelman have you tried deleting the app from the device and reinstalling?  Check the location privacy settings for your app. Is maps able to get the device location?

Comment: Oh yes reinstalling made the error go away.